# Unable to run pkgin on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, sqlite, osx-mavericks, package-managers

I have been attempting to install pkgin on Mac OS X Mavericks. My process was as follows.

- *curl -s http://pkgsrc.joyent.com/packages/Darwin/bootstrap/bootstrap-2014Q2-i386.tar.gz
  | sudo tar -zxpf - -C /*
- creating /etc/paths.d/pkgsrc
- creating .bash_profile to initialize $MANPATH
- *sudo pkgin update*
- *sudo pkgin -y install tmux*

The problem seems to be with SQLite3, as /var/db/pkgin/sql.log looks as follows. Some forums seem to suggest that the query abort has to do with returning a null value rather than 0. When I run the first two queries manually, though, I see valid data in the DB. The third query returns nothing. Does sqlite3 or sqlite3_exec need to be properly configured for this to work?

```
SQL error: callback requested query abort
SQL query: SELECT PKGDB_MTIME FROM PKGDB;
SQL error: callback requested query abort
SQL query: SELECT FULLPKGNAME,PKGNAME,PKGPATH FROM LOCAL_PKG WHERE PKG_KEEP IS NOT NULL;
SQL error: callback requested query abort
SQL query: SELECT FULLPKGNAME,PKGNAME,PKGVERS,COMMENT,FILE_SIZE,SIZE_PKG,CATEGORIES,PKGPATH FROM REMOTE_PKG ORDER BY FULLPKGNAME ASC;
SQL error: callback requested query abort
SQL query: SELECT FULLPKGNAME,PKGNAME,PKGVERS,COMMENT,FILE_SIZE,SIZE_PKG,CATEGORIES,PKGPATH FROM REMOTE_PKG ORDER BY FULLPKGNAME ASC;
```

Comment: Are you sure pkgin is even supported on Mac OS X? If you just want to build packages for your system, you may want to consider [Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew) instead.

Comment: Homebrew will not install sshpass, which is what got me going on this to begin with. pkgsrc/pkgin was recommended as the best package manager for Mac OS X by onthelambda.com. Also, you may notice that the version of pkgin that I am installing is the Darwin version.

Comment: Consider creating a homebrew recipe for sshpass? It's pretty straightforward to do, and will benefit more than just yourself if you contribute it upstream. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Save OS X?

https://github.com/cmacrae/saveosx

If you follow the steps in the installation section, you'll be greeted by an interactive script. In a nutshell, this script will walk you through the set-up of pkgsrc, pkgin, set up your PATH & optionally implement X11 (using XQuartz) in a seamless manner.