# Issue completing the install script for pkgin/pkgsrc for OSX 10.7, segfault running pkgin

Tags: macos, osx-lion, failed-installation, netbsd

In attempting to install `pkgin`/`pkgsrc` (NetBSD-based package managment tools), using the saveosx.org instructions and github repository.

The repository has [installation instructions](https://github.com/cmacrae/saveosx#installation), which I followed, up to the point of a specific but uninformative error:

```
It looks like there was an issue running: sudo /usr/pkg/bin/pkgin -y update
```

I tried running this file directly, but my terminal reports a segmentation fault.

I'm running OSX 10.7.5 and have Xcode-Command-Line Tools installed, but I find no information about Darwin version compatibility on NetBSD's site. My searches have revealed no one else reporting issues using `pkgin`.

Version 5.0+ is supported according to www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/platforms.html#darwin, which according to wikipedia (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29#Release_history) corresponds to OSX 10.1.1+

What options do I have besides upgrading my operating system and hoping the problem is fixing by having newer libraries or a newer kernel?

For reference:

- www.pkgsrc.org/#docs
- www.perkin.org.uk/pages/pkgsrc-binary-packages-for-osx.html
- wiki.netbsd.org/pkgsrc/pkgsrc_64bit_osx/
- Related question: [Unable to run pkgin on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150053/unable-to-run-pkgin-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the `pkgin` binary currently supplied by `saveosx` is compiled only for more recent OSX releases.  It needs at least a Darwin-14.x kernel, or newer, so it won't even run on 10.9.5.  Unfortunately the script fails to check the OSX version before it blindly tries to run the `pkgin` binary, causing the program to crash.

`saveosx` is basically a painfully obnoxious, rather ugly, and poorly implemented. set of scripts that are superfluous to actually using `pkgsrc` on OSX.

I would **strongly** recommend avoiding `saveosx` for the time being.

Instead I would recommend trying the following well supported alternative:

[OSX binary pkgsrc packages](http://pkgsrc.joyent.com/install-on-osx/)

A 32-bit Snow Leopard version that runs on 10.6.8 and newer is available, and I just checked the distribution directory and I see some 2015Q1 i386 packages are just now available, still supporting 10.6.8:

[2015Q1 32-bit (i386) Snow Leopard and newer pkgsrc bootstrap](http://pkgsrc.joyent.com/packages/Darwin/bootstrap/bootstrap-2015Q1-i386.tar.gz)

You can of course also build your own `pkgsrc` `bootstrap` for any specific OSX environment:

[pkgsrc home](http://www.pkgsrc.org/)

Comment: `bootstrap` looks like a good answer...and it's on the homepage. Between that suggestion, advice on avoiding `saveosx`, and a link to the packages still supporting 10.6.8, I don't think this answer could be any more complete. Thanks.